# Is there something like firebug for actionscript?

Tags: actionscript

I'm totally new to actionscript,

and such a tool like firebug will really help a lot!

Answer (score 3):

I like very much MonsterDebugger, easy to use, for Flash, Flex, AIR.
Check it out here - http://www.monsterdebugger.com/

Answer (score 0):

> Alcon is a lightweight debugging tool
>   for ActionScript developers that
>   provides several straightforward and
>   quickly accessible methods to debug
>   any ActionScript 2 or ActionScript 3
>   application, be it from the Web
>   Browser, the standalone Flash Player
>   or an AIR Runtime.

**[Alcon](http://blog.hexagonstar.com/alcon/)**

[Introducing the ActionScript 3.0 debugger](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/as3_debugger.html)

[Trace and debug ActionScript from your browser](http://www.actionscript.org/resources/articles/207/1/Trace-and-debug-ActionScript-from-your-browser/Page1.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you're developing Flex or Air applications then I would definitely recommend the Eclipse 
IDE with the Flex SDK plugin.

http://www.adobe.com/products/flex/flexdownloads/

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Flash environment try pressing Control-Shift-Enter to launch your swf. This will open up the debugger (press the green arrow to begin code execution).

If you're using Flex Builder you will have a full fledged [debugger](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/as3_debugger.html) at your disposal.

In either environment you can set break points, these are points you can specify in your code where code execution needs to halt so you can investigate what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LocalConnection` class to communicate with other swfs. I use this concept for viewing traced messages in browser.

- Create a debugger SWF that accepts local connection requests and displays all the incoming text in a text area.
- Write a Debug class with a static write method that sends the incoming text to the debugger thru local connection (and optionally traces the message).
- Include the Debug class in your app and replace all trace calls with Debug.write
- (Optional) Write fancy methods writeError writeWarning that displays the important messages in different colors.
- Run the debugger swf in the browser.

I have the code for these, but does SO allow posting files? The code grew a little long when I implemented searching and highlighting the console with regex.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using command-line tools (rather than flex builder or flashIDE) you can use the command-line debugger, FDB. You can find it in your flexSDK/bin folder. There is plenty of documentation out there for this (fairly frustrating) tool.

Answer (score 0):

http://blog.coursevector.com/flashbug